# Lodash map value from nested object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to use a lodash's map function to extract a value from a nested object in an array of objects and store it in a new key. But always got stuck with lodash and am getting an error. Any help would be much appreciated. The key `nested` will always be an array of 1 object.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

var all_data = [{id: 'A', nested: [{id: '123'}]}, {id: 'B', nested: [{id: '456'}]}];

_.map(all_data, (data) => ({
  data.nested_id = data.nested[0].id;

}));
console.log(all_data)
```

Desired output: `[{id: 'A', nested_id: '123', nested: [{id: '123'}]}, {id: 'B', nested_id: '456', nested: [{id: '456'}]}]`

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using lodash? The immediate problem is that you should return `data` from the callback of `_.map` but this can be done in pure JS and without mutation: `all_data.map((obj) => ({ ...obj, nested_id: obj.nested[0].id }))`

Comment: I think you are better off using Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use lodash for this simple transformation.

```js
const allData = [{id: 'A', nested: [{id: '123'}]}, {id: 'B', nested: [{id: '456'}]}]

const transformedData = allData.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  nested_id: item.nested[0].id
}))
```

But here's the lodash version if you really want to use it.

```js
const transformedData = _.map(allData, (item) => ({
  ...item,
  nested_id: item.nested[0].id,
}))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great. As a slight variant if I wanted to removed the property `nested` is it possible to do with the way that spread operator is used?

Comment: @user2242044 If you know the object only has the 3 properties shared in the code snippet, you can do `allData.map(item => ({ id: item.id, nested_id: item.nested[0].id }))`

Comment: thanks. This was just a simple example. What if it has a lot more fields than just 3 and I don't want to write them all out?